Importing same class into two content scripts causes - Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist when
Developing a Chrome extension. I have a class DomUtils that I'm importing in both of my contentscripts - a and b.
The issue is that whenever I run the code, I get Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
This error does not occur when I comment out DomUtils import in either of the contentscripts (a or b) and leave it in only one content script (So if I only import DomUtils in a or in b, it works fine).
For some reason, importing DomUtils in both my contentscripts causes this issue.
manifest.json:
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*mysite.com"],
            "js": ["a.js"]
        },
        {
            "matches": ["anothersite.com"],
            "js": ["b.js"]
        }
    ]

And here is the mechanism for passing messages:
background.js:
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { ... })

Receiving in contentScripts:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async function(...) {
    // doing some async actions...
})

I'm also using Webpack. Could the issue be related to it?
Edit: adding DomUtils:
export class DomUtils {
    private selectorDelay: number;
    private selectorTimeout: number;

    constructor(site, selectorDelay = 200, selectorTimeout = 10000) {
        console.log('initializing domUtils')
        this.selectorDelay = selectorDelay
        this.selectorTimeout = selectorTimeout
    }

    setSelectorOptions(selectorDelay, selectorTimeout) {
        this.selectorDelay = selectorDelay
        this.selectorTimeout = selectorTimeout
    }

    // some dom methods...



It's unclear how the parts you've shown are actually connected/imported and where the error is shown exactly (in the tab or in the background script). See MCVE - it must be complete enough to be verifiable.
